# how to input an ID and reflect different results in two separate tabs in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

This maybe a general question and I will try my best to describe it explicitly. In R Shiny and the `ui.R` file, I use `radioButtons` to select one of the two methods:

```
  radioButtons("Methods", strong("Choose a Method:"),
                 choices = list("method_1" = "m1",
                                "method_2" = "m2"),
                 selected="method_1"),

  selectInput("method_2_ID", strong("Choose an ID (method_2"),
                topIDs)

  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel(title = "method_1_tab1", 
               plotOutput("plots"), 
      tabPanel(title = "method_2_output1", 
               tableOutput("m2_output1")),
      tabPanel(title = "method_2_output2", 
               verbatimTextOutput("m2_output2")))
    ))
```

You can see for method_2, I plan to use two different tabs to show different results, i.e. `m2_output1` and `m2_output2`. In my `server.R` file, I use:

```
if (input$Methods == "method_2") {

  # m2_output1
  updateTabsetPanel(session, "method_2_output1", selected="panel2")

  # drop-down menu
  SelectedID = reactive(function(){
    input$method_2_ID
  })

  # m2_output1
  output$m2_output1 = renderTable({
    m2[m2$ID == input$method_2_ID, ]
  })

  # m2_output2
  updateTabsetPanel(session, "method_2_output2", selected="panel3")

  [...]
  output$m2_output2 = renderPrint({
     [...]
    }
  })
```

However, it works only for the `method_2_output1` tab when I click the ID from the drop-down menu, and when I click the `method_2_ouptut2` tab, there is nothing displayed (should display `verbatimTextOutput("m2_output2)"`, I think). Is there anything wrong with my `ui.R` or `server.R` files?

Comment: Does your `output$m2_output2` depend on `input$method_2_ID`? What is in your `output$m2_output2`?

Comment: @sgibb: yes, I will use `input$method_2_ID` in the calculations (as I omitted in the `[...]` part under `# m2_output2`. The output of `m2_output2` are just some printing results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There were quite a few changes needed to get the tabs to do what you wanted.

Some of the bigger changes were:

1. You have to create the `tabsetPanel` and the `tabPanels` with the `id` arguments, so that they can be referenced.
2. For `updateTabsetPanel` to work, you have to wrap those commands inside a reactive observer using:

   ```
   observe ( {
    #updateTabsetPanel here
   })
   ```
3. Called ShinyServer with a `sessions` argument

I made several other changes. Below is a fully working framework. When you select Method 1, it selects Tab1. If you choose Method 2, if switches between the second and the third tab, depending on the Method ID chosen.
[image]

#### UI.R

```
library("shiny")

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(    
  headerPanel("Tab Switch Demo"),
  sidebarPanel(
         h4('Switch Tabs Based on Methods'),
             radioButtons(inputId="method", label="Choose a Method",
                          choices = list("method_1",
                                         "method_2")),
         conditionalPanel("input.method== 'method_2' ",                          
                          selectInput("method_2_ID", strong("Choose an ID for method 2"),
                                      choices = list("method_2_1",
                                                     "method_2_2"))
                          )       

    ),
  mainPanel(
          tabsetPanel(id ="methodtabs",
            tabPanel(title = "First Method Plot", value="panel1",
                     plotOutput("method_1_tab1")),
            tabPanel(title = "method_2_output1", value="panel2",
                     tableOutput("m2_output1")),
            tabPanel(title = "method_2_output2", value="panel3",
                     verbatimTextOutput("m2_output2"))
            )
      )  
))
```

#### Server.R

```
library('shiny')    
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  output$method_1_tab1 = renderPlot({
    plot(cars)
  })
  output$m2_output1 = renderText({
    "First Tab for Method 2, ID=1"
  })
  output$m2_output2 = renderText({
    "Second Tab for Method 2, ID=2"
  })

  observe({
    if (input$method == "method_1") {    
      updateTabsetPanel(session, inputId="methodtabs", selected="panel1")
    }      
    else if (input$method_2_ID == "method_2_1") {    
      updateTabsetPanel(session, inputId="methodtabs", selected="panel2")
    }      
    else if (input$method_2_ID == "method_2_2") {    
      updateTabsetPanel(session, inputId="methodtabs", selected="panel3")
    }      
  })
```

Use the code above as the starting point, and start making changes.

Hope that helps you get going.